# How to find dead tuples (fragmentation) in PostgreSQL 8.2 ( for Greenplum)?

Tags: sql, greenplum

I want to find dead tuples and live tuples of tables in PostgreSQL 8.2. We have just started with Greenplum MPP Database system which is based on PostgreSQL 8.2.

Because of default MVCC architecture, we need to find dead tuples of a table and make plan to VACUUM it.

I know, how to find dead tuples in the new version of PostgreSQL. I have already shared two article on this.

[**PostgreSQL: How to check Table Fragmentation using pgstattuple module**](http://www.dbrnd.com/2016/12/postgresql-how-to-check-table-fragmentation-using-pgstattuple-module-remove-dead-tuple-vacuum-analyze/)

[**PostgreSQL: Script to find total Live Tuples and Dead Tuples (Row) of a Table**](http://www.dbrnd.com/2016/10/postgresql-script-to-find-total-live-tuples-and-dead-tuples-row-of-a-table-execute-vacuum-remove-fragmentation-improve-performance/)

Can any one help me on this?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If it is based on PostgreSQL 8.2, it should have autovacuum. Use that rather than trying to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yes autovacuum is there, but I have many tables and each of size is around 150GB. So I need manual activity as well.

Comment: Why? Can't you configure autovacuum so that it does what you need?

Comment: I already set force auto vacuum, but still it is skipping for many tables. You can visit this article to make force auto-vacuum. http://www.dbrnd.com/2016/08/postgresql-force-autovacuum-for-running-aggressive-improve-performance-of-autovacuum-frequent-run/

Comment: If tables are not autovacuumed often enough, reduce [`autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-VACUUM-SCALE-FACTOR). You can even set it to zero and set [`autovacuum_vacuum_threshold`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-VACUUM-THRESHOLD) to an appropriate high value. You can even set these parameters different for different tables.

Comment: @Anvesh greenplum provides a view that might be able to solve your use case. Try select * from gp_toolkit.gp_bloat_diag; This view contains information regarding actual size of table on the disk and expected size of table based on table statistics. Column 'bdidiag' displays how much bloat is there in the table. Table bloat is accumulation of free space used by old data rows within the table data files.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe though greenplum is a fork of 8.2, autovacuum is disabled.

Comment: Thanks @valarDohaeris. It works for me

Answer (score 4):

Don't use autovacuum.  Greenplum isn't PostgreSQL and autovacuum does not work in the database.  I highly recommend not tagging Greenplum posts with PostgreSQL because you will likely get incorrect information.  It would be like posting a question about OSX and also tagging BSD.

Vacuum Heap tables with bloat:

```
psql -t -A -c "SELECT E'VACUUM \"' || bdinspname || E'\".\"' || bdirelname || E'\";' FROM gp_toolkit.gp_bloat_diag WHERE bdinspname <> 'pg_catalog'" | psql -e
```

But most all of your tables in Greenplum will likely not be heap based which uses MVCC and instead use "Append Optimized" or AO for short.  It uses a visibility map to hide deleted rows and the files are smaller so it is faster.  It also allows the table to be compressed and column oriented.

AO tables also need maintenance but unlike heap tables, it has a compaction threshold built in controlled by gp_appendonly_compaction_threshold GUC.  Just VACUUM all AO tables and the database will automatically rebuild the table if the percentage of hidden rows exceeds 10%.

Greenplum still suffers from the freeze age problem that was inherited from PostgreSQL.  This script typically won't return any rows but on older installations with tables that haven't been touched in a very long time, you might start to vacuum tables.

```
vacuum_freeze_min_age=$(psql -t -A -c "show vacuum_freeze_min_age;")
psql -t -A -c "SELECT E'VACUUM \"' || n.nspname || E'\".\"' || c.relname || E'\";' FROM pg_class c join pg_namespace n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid WHERE age(relfrozenxid) > $vacuum_freeze_min_age AND c.relkind = 'r'" | psql -e
```

While you are at it, you should schedule analyzedb to analyze all tables on a regular basis.  Example:

```
analyzedb -d gpadmin -s tpcds
```

Don't forget the catalog!

```
psql -t -A -c "SELECT E'VACUUM ANALYZE \"' || n.nspname || E'\".\"' || c.relname || E'\";' FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid WHERE n.nspname = 'pg_catalog' AND c.relkind = 'r'" | psql -e
```

This reindexes the catalog indexes:

```
reindexdb -s
```

Comment: I removed the Postgres tag right after the question was posted, but Anvesh added it back in and I didn't want to start an edit war

Comment: Thanks Jon, will check this solution and get back to you. also removed postgresql tag.